# Как использовать\дублировать методы репозитория для работы с вложенными документами в MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем добрый вечер. Я новичок в MongoDb, работаю с c# driver, (версия выше 2.1), работаю с добавлением бд в проект.

Пусть есть обобщенный IRepository типа:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    T GetById(Guid Id);

    IQueryable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    IQueryable<T> GetMatchesBy<TKey>(TKey keyFilter, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector);

    IQueryable<T> GetAll();

    PaginatedList<T> Paginate<TKey>(
        int pageIndex, int pageSize,
        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector);

    PaginatedList<T> Paginate<TKey>(
        int pageIndex, int pageSize,
        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    //Others

}
```

И реализация для Mongo например :

```
public class MongoRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private readonly IMongoClient client;

    private readonly IMongoDatabase database;

    private readonly IMongoCollection<T> collection;

    public  MongoRepository(string ConnectionString, string DatabaseName)
    {
        client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
        database = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
        collection = database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }


    #region IRepository Members



    public T GetById(Guid Id) 
    {
        var result = collection.AsQueryable()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(Id));
        return result;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
    {
        var result = collection.AsQueryable()
                        .Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Пусть есть коллекция из документов типа

```
public class EntryTree : IEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public List<EntryTreeNode> TreeNodes { get; set; }

    //Others
}
```

И недавно в слое Сервисов появилась острая необходимость добавления методов работы со вложенными документами типа `EntryTreeNode`.

```
public interface IVocabularyService
{
    PaginatedList<EntryTreeNode> GetEntryTreeNodes(
        Guid entryTreeId, 
        int pageIndex, int pageSize);

    PaginatedList<EntryTreeNode> GetEntryTreeNodesBy(
        Guid entryTreeId, 
        int pageIndex, int pageSize, 
        Expression<Func<EntryTreeNode, bool>> predicate);

    PaginatedList<EntryTreeNode> SearchEntryTreeNodesBy(
        Guid entryTreeId, 
        string searchString, 
        int pageIndex, int pageSize);
}
```

Однако, в реализации `VocabularyService` я не могу типизировать  `MongoRepository<T>` типом `EntryTreeNode`, он же представляет коллекцию вложенных документов.

Но в слое Сервисов хотелось бы использовать некоторые методы, реализованные в репозитории, для вложенных документов `List<EntryTreeNode> TreeNodes`.

Как лучшим образом решить эту проблему?